# Magento 2 problem with tax

Tags: magento2, tax

I've  set tax 23% for taxable class.

Then I set option "I've enter prices in catalog Magento with tax". Then I set for every place display price with tax.

[image]

59,99 zł is correct product price in catalog backend and in frontend.
when I add product to the basket, then I see price 59,99zł as without tax and system charge extra 23% tax.

But I enable option  catalog prices includes tax, What is going on?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Potrzebujesz pomocy jeszcze?
Proszę ustaw poprawny adres wysyłki.

Do you need help yet? Please set correct shipping adres in:

Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping settings -> Origin (here please set your country)

Now tax should be look good :)

Comment: I confirm this solution for same problem :)